# `MetaTransactionOptions` not found in `@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types`

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm trying to add Account Abstraction with Relay to one of my dapp. I'm following documentation available on the official docs: docs.safe.global .

I'm following documentation to add relay provided here: https://docs.safe.global/learn/safe-core/safe-core-account-abstraction-sdk/relay-kit

Current package versions:

```
    "@safe-global/api-kit": "^1.1.0",
    "@safe-global/auth-kit": "^1.0.0",
    "@safe-global/protocol-kit": "^1.0.1",
    "@safe-global/relay-kit": "^1.0.0",
    "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "^1.9.2",
```

When I import `MetaTransactionOptions` from `@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types@1.9.2`, I get this compiler error:

```
'"@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types"' has no exported member named 'MetaTransactionOptions'. Did you mean 'TransactionOptions'?
```

Was MetaTransactionOptions updated to TransactionOptions?